# FOL Inference - Resolution proof step problem

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

In the popular FOL problem "Criminal West" of the Book [AI Modern Approach](https://books.google.lk/books?id=8jZBksh-bUMC), I'm unable to understand how it gets from step 3 to 4 in the proof tree as highlighted in this picture.

[Image of proof tree of Criminal West problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW1kx.png)

In the previous step I thought it like follows but I cannot get how Missile(y) replaces Weapon(y)

> If American(West) is true then ¬American(West) becomes false and the
>   remaining part should be true.

Answer (score 0):

**Missile(x) does not replace Weapon(x);**

Here is how the process of unification of clauses works at this level:

$$\neg Missile(x) \lor \underbrace{Weapon(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \neg Weapon(y)}_{\binom{\text{cancellable under the cond.}}{\text{that} \ x \ \text{is identified with} \ y.}} \lor \neg Sells(West,y,z) \lor \neg Hostile(z)$$

$$\text{Yielding the new clause:}$$

$$\neg Missile(y) \lor  \neg Sells(West,y,z) \lor \neg Hostile(z)$$

The Weapons are "destroyed" in the process...

Remark: instead of keeping $y$, it could have been $x$...